# Qt animation for groupbox

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a groupbox to which I want to add animation.
I created my custom group box class and implemented the mouster enter and leave event.
On mouse enter , I check the height and decrease or increase it with animation but does not seem to work .

```
int height = groupBox->height();

if ( height >= 40 ) // if height is already increased set , decrease it. 
    {

       int groupBoxHeight = 15;

       QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(groupBox, "geometry");
       animation->setDuration(2000);
       animation->setStartValue(QRect(this->x(), this->y(), this->width(), this->height()));
       animation->setEndValue(QRect(this->x(), this->y(), this->width(), groupBoxHeight));
       animation->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::OutBounce);
       animation->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
    }
    else
    {
        int groupboxHeight = 50;
        groupBox->setGeometry(groupBox->geometry().x(), groupBox->geometry().y(), groupBox->width(), groupboxHeight);

        QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(groupBox, "geometry");
       animation->setDuration(2000);
       animation->setStartValue(QRect(this->x(), this->y(), this->width(), this->height()));
       animation->setEndValue(QRect(this->x(), this->y(), this->width(), groupboxHeight));
       animation->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::OutBounce);
       animation->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);

    }
```

Comment: If you added the groupbox to a layout, you cannot change its geometry manually because it's managed by the layout. Try to use `maximumSize` property instead. Layouts will respect this value.

Comment: Thats right, I had added it to layout. If I set maximumSze for group box , it works.

Comment: Does animation work now?

Answer (score 0):

it may work if you add `QSpacerItem`s to the containing layout or even better to set the size of the `groupbox` to `FixedSize`. the fixed size might cause problems when you dynamically add and remove items but it could help